# C++ - Python Binding with ctypes - Return multiple values in function

Tags: python, c++, binding, ctypes

I found this example of C++ Python binding: 
[Calling C/C++ from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)
According to the answer there, I created some testfiles:

foo.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


int bar_2(int a, int b){
    return a*b;
}

std::pair<int, int> divide(int dividend, int divisor)
{
   return std::make_pair(dividend / divisor, dividend % divisor);
}

extern "C" {
    int bar_2_py(int a, int b){ return bar_2(a,b); }
    std::pair<int, int> divide_py(int d, int div){return divide(d,div);}
}
```

fooWrapper.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

def bar_2(a, b):
    res = lib.bar_2_py( a,b )
    return res

def divide(d,div):
    res = lib.divide_py(d,div)
    return res
```

Then

```
g++ -c -fPIC foo.cpp -o foo.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  foo.o
```

creates libfoo.so

If I import it and run the functions in iPython I get the right value for function "bar_2" but a (partly) wrong answer for "divide":

```
from fooWrapper import bar_2, divide
bar_2(10,2) # returns 20, which is right
divide(10,3) # returns 3
```

Obviously, the return-value is right for the first value of the pair (as 10/3 int division is 3). But the second value was getting lost.

So, what would be best practice to obtain multiple values (in this case 2 integer values)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think `ctypes` allows one to translate `std::pair` to a python tuple without much boilerplate code. Especially since `std::pair` is a feature of the `c++11` standard, and `ctypes` only works with `c`-style functions [citation / verification needed].

I suggest would using *output parameters*, the `c` way to return multiple values. The idea is simple, the `c`-function returns it's values by pointer, `example.c`:

```
void divide_modulo(int a, int b, int *div, int *rest)
{
    *div  = a / b;
    *rest = a % b;
}
```

Then compile it to a shared library:

```
gcc -o libexample.so -shared example.c
```

The `libexample.so` now allows you to write to python integers via a pointer in `c` which are passes as parameters like this:

```py
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libexample.so')

def divide_modulo(a, b):
  div = ctypes.c_int(0)
  rest = ctypes.c_int(0)
  lib.divide_modulo(a, b, ctypes.byref(div), ctypes.byref(rest))
  return (div.value, rest.value)

print(divide_modulo(11, 4))
```

The `ctypes.byref` wrapper when calling `lib.divide_modulo` with `div` and `rest` converts an `int` to a pointer to an `int`.